# Best way to create ListView for Android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-listfragment

I am beginner. I am looking for Tutorials of Swipe / Refresh / Listview with adapter which Data comes from Parser.com. I can't find in the web the suitable one!

I tried a lot of one but nothing work well.

1. Can you advice where can I get one is working well and easy to understand?
2. I work with Fragments, I don't know if it is correct way to work with theses fragment to create ListView?

Your help will be appreciated!
Regards,
Marwan

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing here because I can't comment. 
I learned how to use list view from 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSZLqBWKTHw 
and
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

As for using fragments, You can put them in fragments. I would do that if the fragment would be used in more than one activity or if you want make use of space in larger screens.